# Boolean expression (x / 2) * 2 == x to test

Tags: java, boolean

This is actually one of my lab questions.

You can test to see if an integer, x, is even or odd using the Boolean expression (x / 2) * 2 == x. Integers that are even make this expression true, and odd integers make the expression false. Use a for loop to iterate five times. With each iteration, request an integer from the user. Print each integer the user types, and whether it is even or odd. Keep up with the number of even
and odd integers the user types, and print “Done” when finished, so the user won’t try to type another integer. Finally, print out the number of even and odd integers that were entered.

I basically know what this question requires me to do. However, I don’t quite understand why boolean expression, (x/2)*2 == x, can test whether the integer is an ever number or an odd number. Lets say my number is 59, which is an odd integer obviously. 59 divided by 2 is 29.5. 29.5 times 2, which equals 59. No matter what x is, (x/2)*2 always equals x. So how to make this expression false when the integer is an odd. Then I can determine what I should print.

Comment: Have you even tried `59/2`? In Java `int/int = int`.

Comment: Use modulo base two and check if the remainder is zero or 1

Comment: 59/2 = 29.5 
29.5 * 2 = 59
no matter what number I have for x, (x/2)*2 always equals x...

Comment: Please, try it in Java. Don't forget that they are `int`egers, not `float`s nor `double`s.

Comment: i know how to use modulo. But the question doesn't ask us to use modulo...

Comment: @coding `59 / 2 = 29`.

Comment: I think your assignment may even be intended to force you to face the fact that there are many different ways of doing arithmetic. Java `int` has its rules. Java `double` has a different set of rules. None of them are real number arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're dealing with integers, there's always a rounding down to the nearest round number.

`59/2 = 29` when all elements are integers.

Multiplying the result by 2 gives `58`, so since the 2 numbers aren't the same, we deduce that the number, 59, is odd.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code written in a beginners way, if u still don't understand something just ask. The formula x==(x/2)*2 is used because when you are dividing two integer variables the result is always a round number, which later if it's odd, won't give u the same initial number. (59/2=29  => 29*2=58  => false)...

```
import java.util.*;

public class EvenOrOdd{

   public static void main( String [] args){

   Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

   boolean result=true;

List<Integer> EvenNums = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
List<Integer> OddNums = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ 

   System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

   int x=scan.nextInt();

   if(x==(x/2)*2){  
       result=true;
       System.out.println(result); 
       EvenNums.add(x);  
       continue;

    }else if(x!=(x/2)*2){  
       result=false; 
       System.out.println(result);
       OddNums.add(x); 
       continue;

      }
  }
 System.out.println("Done");   

 System.out.println("Even numbers are: " + EvenNums);
 System.out.println("Odd numbers are: " + OddNums);

 }
}
```